# How to run a script, depending on internet connection

Tags: networking, sshfs

I often mount a remote drive using sshfs. I would love to have this mount automatically. However, if I mount it in my .bashrc or startup scripts, the mount often fails because my wireless internet connection has not yet been made.

Does anybody know of an easy way to execute a bash scrip every time the connection is made, or to auto-mount an sshfs drive?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Add your script to `/etc/network/if-up.d/`.
Name your script without a '.sh' extension.

Also after adding script run `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/yourscriptname` to give necessary permission.

Make sure the network interface (e.g. wlan0 or eth0) that should trigger your script when turned on is mentioned in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: inside scripts in `/etc/network/*.d/` you can use the variable `$IFACE` to know which interface is getting a connection so you can skip the procedure if it is the wired connection for example.

Comment: Is there a way to specify which specific network you want to do this for? when it's my home network I want to do the script but when I'ts a network out and about I might not want to...

Comment: this actually doesn't seem to work at all. I know my scripts work because I can run them using ./ in the terminal and they work but when I toggle off and on the connection, the scripts are not called at all. Is there anything that I have to do to reference them in someway? dropping a script in if-up.d seems to be lacking a step?!?!

Comment: check whether they hace correct permissions please.

Comment: Please add what exactly should go into `interfaces` when it is not there. Is it `auto wlan0` and `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` or sth else?

Comment: I want to know whether it's enough to just have `auto lo` `iface lo inet loopback` in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file. I want my script to be executed after connecting with `eth0`.

Comment: This link would be helpfull to you I think http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-run-firewall-script-as-soon-as-eth0-interface-brings-up.html

Comment: More on Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, if I add to `/etc/network/interfaces` `auto wlp58s0 
iface wlp58s0 inet dhcp 
post-up /home/augustin/Config/auto-checkin.sh` the wifi doesn't start after reboot... :(

Comment: From what I can tell this answer is no longer applicable as of Ubuntu 17.10 due to the deprecation of NETWORKING and it's replacement, NETPLAN.  I wonder how this answer can be updated to work with Netplan?

Answer (score 25):

*Editor's note: Cuttlefish hasn't been updated since 2012 and is not in any current Ubuntu repositories*

### Ubuntu 12.04

- Install [Cuttlefish](https://launchpad.net/cuttlefish):  A simple tool, which realises reflexes on your computer by executing actions when specific events are triggered.
- Open Cuttlefish and click on <kbd>New</kbd>.

  [image: Step-1]

  - Give it a name, and change *Activated by stimulus* option to ON.
  - Click on *Stimulus*, select the category *Network* and type *Connect to WLAN*. Click OK.

  [image: Step 2]

  - You can also select the SSID of wireless network and you have an option of whether or not to check this on startup.

  [image: Step 3]

  - Now you will have to specify a reaction. Go to *Reaction* tab, and click add. Select *Applications* from the category and *Start Application (in advanced mode)* from type.

  [image: Step 4]

  - Now specify the script which you want to run in executable option. You can even pass parameters to the script.

  [image: Step-5]

  - And that's it! Also make sure that you add Cuttlefish in startup applications. Go to *Edit > Preferences* and enable the autostart option.

  [image: Step-6]

Comment: cuttlefish is completely broken and hasn't seen an update for sometime. I wish it could get more development because we need something like Android's Tasker app for Linux. Nobody wants to mess with etc/network/interfaces and if-up folders and scripts. Just give me something I can click or toggle on and off.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer this part of the OP question: "I would love to have this mount automatically"

My favorite tool for automounting network shares is autofs:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

AutoFS is my tool of choice to mount my NAS - for all my laptops and workstations.

"*autofs is a program for automatically mounting directories on an as-needed basis. Auto-mounts are mounted only as they are accessed, and are unmounted after a period of inactivity. Because of this, automounting NFS/Samba shares conserves bandwidth and offers better overall performance compared to static mounts via fstab.*"

Comment: Your answer while possible may be a bit late as the OP already accepted the other answer. Your help is of course appreciated, however you might be better served by focusing your efforts on the [unanswered questions](//askubuntu.com/unanswered)

Comment: Sorry Wayne, RBell got the last laugh here -- the best answer (about using Cuttlefish) is no longer relevant because that package is outdated -- but autofs still exists, and I hadn't seen it if not for this post. Thanks, RBell!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm concerned, the `/etc/network/if-up.d/` solution did not work from me as when I added to `/etc/network/interfaces` the following:

```
auto wlp58s0
iface wlp58s0 inet dhcp
post-up /home/augustin/Config/myscript.sh
```

Wifi would start after reboot.

But after some struggle, from [this link](http://www.techytalk.info/start-script-on-network-manager-successful-connection/), what worked was to add the script to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` in the form `90myscript.sh` where `90` is the priority level of the script and with the following form:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
IF=$1
STATUS=$2
 
if [ "$IF" == "wlp58s0" ]
then
    case "$2" in
        up)
        # interface is up
        ;;
        down)
        # interface will be down
        ;;
        pre-up)
        # interface will be up
        ;;
        post-down)
        # interface is down
        ;;
        *)
        ;;
    esac
fi
```

I guess there are issues between who controls the network config at system level and sometimes the default `network` behavior is left behind the dispatcher one.

Also, for those who would like - like me - to try to have a symbolic link to the script (to store the file in a better location), unfortunately it did not work for me.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`systemd` seems to have taken over networking nowadays.

```
$ networkctl
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged
  2 enp0s25          ether              n/a         unmanaged
  3 wlo1             wlan               n/a         unmanaged

3 links listed.
```

It also has units corresponding to the interfaces

```
$ systemctl list-units |grep wlo1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.3-0000:24:00.0-net-wlo1.device                                                        loaded active plugged   Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (3x3 AGN)
sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device                                                                                   loaded active plugged   Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (3x3 AGN)
```

Apparently you can use these in service unit files. So just create a service unit to run your script and use something like that inside to make it run conditionally on the network:

```
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device
```

Good luck! I haven't tested this, so "your mileage may vary".

Sources:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257888/systemd-wait-for-network-interface-to-be-up-before-running-service

Answer (score 1):

The best, simple and easy way would be to add an up command to what ever interface on which you want work on.

Interfaces can be found in the "/etc/network/" directory under the file name "interfaces"

```
iface elan0 inet manual
    up filename.sh
```

This will add the up command to elan0. Simillarly give this to what ever interface you want to work on. Remember to indent one tab space.

Make sure you give the execute permissions to the file.

```
sudo chmod 755 filename.sh
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works with `tun0` VPN interfaces managed by `network-manager`. The key is the use of `inet manual`.