# How to display a message each time eth1 is enabled?

Tags: command-line

How can I display a message like:

> eth1 interface has been enabled

each time when eth1 is enabled?

Let me know if my question make sense.

Comment: You don't get notifications when your network is enabled or disabled? All modern operating systems are doing this. Why you should let reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I want to change that message.

Comment: I don'd see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu There doesn't have to be anything wrong with it good grief. If he wants to change it, what is that to you?

Answer (score 0):

After some searches, I found a way how you can do it:

- First, disable the usual notification from  Network Manager. How? Your answer is here:

  - [How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager)
- Run a script to notify you every time internet connects. How? Here is your answer:

  - [How to run a script, depending on internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-every-time-internet-connects)
- How you can get notified from a script? Again, there are answers on Stack Exchange in this sense:

  - [Is there a way to show notification from bash script in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu)
  - [Sound notification in Ubuntu terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273098/sound-notification-in-ubuntu-terminal)

Comment: @AdrianGeorge So, it was useful the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shell script into `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` that you might name `99-notification`. Be sure to mark it executable with `chmod +x 99-notification`.

In that script, you will need to do something with the input to script, the interface name and the action.

```
#/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" = eth1 ]] && [[ "$2" = up ]]
then
    DISPLAY=:0.0 kdialog --passivepopup "eth1 is enabled" 3
fi
```

I have not tested this, but I think it will work, at least with KDE. For Unity/Gnome, you might have to exchange `kdialog` with `zenity`.