# Execute script after successful network connection

Tags: 18.04

How do I automatically execute a script after an internet connection is successfully made.

I've tried placing the script in if-up.d and it just does not work and I can't find any documentation on how to do this. The script works if I manually execute.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection

Comment: Which  Ubuntu version are you using? What do you want the script to do?

Comment: @thelaakes I've looked at that thread and tried the solution to the tee but it does not work. I am unsure if my interfaces file is correct. It only has `auto lo  iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: @StephenBoston Ubuntu 18.04. I want my PC to automatically VNC to another PC whenever there is a successful WIFI connection. I just cannot get this to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: If I manually execute the script it works. It asks for my authentication and it VNC into my second PC. It is a simple script `#!/bin/bash  xtightvncviewer 192.168.0.10`. I dont know if this script is executing at all or not when placed into `/etc/network/if-up.d`. Is there a way to check?

Comment: You could add a log line to the script. With 18.04 the network system changed a bit so perhaps you'll have better luck with a systemd service. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805354/systemd-start-service-at-boot-time-after-network-is-really-up-for-wol-purpose  and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230785

Comment: I might revert to an older version of Ubuntu and attempt this again.

Comment: I've attempted this in 16.04 and i get the error in my syslog 'Error: Can't open display'. How do I open the display via my script

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Boston mentioned you could use a systemd service to automate it.

Create a service file under /etc/systemd/system and name it FILENAME.service

Paste this into your file:

```
[Unit]
Description=YOUR DESCRIPTION
Requires=network-online.target 
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/YOUR/PATH/TO/SCRIPT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Type=oneshot means it will only be executed once.

The line **requires=network-online.target** states that the service needs the service network to be online and only executes **after=network-online.target**

[image: You can see the service (test.service) started after the network.service]

You can see the service (test.service) started after the network.service

To finish it up you need to enable the service with the command

```
sudo systemctl enable FILENAME.service
```

Check if your Service is enabled

```
sudo systemctl is-enabled FILENAME.service
```

You can ofcourse manually start or stop the service with

```
sudo systemctl start/stop/restart/status FILENAME.service
```

TIP: Pic was created with `systemd-analyze plot > output.svg`