# Run python script when internet connection becomes available on Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, python

I need to setup a Jetson Nano device so that a Python script is launched everytime an Internet connection is available.

So, referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection), I did the following:

- I created the 'run_when_connection_available' script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# create a dummy folder to check script execution
mkdir /home /user_name/dummy_folder_00

# kill previous instances of the system
pkill python3

# move to folder with python script and launch it
cd /home/user_name/projects/folder
/usr/bin/python3 launcher.py --arg01 --arg02 ...

# create another dummy folder to check script execution
mkdir /home /user_name/dummy_folder_01
```

- I made this script executable and I copied it to /etc/network/if-up.d

Now, everytime I plug the ethernet cable out and in again, I can see the dummy folders are created in /home/user_name, but the python script isn't launched (at least, it doesn't appear in the system monitor). I tried running the command in the script from the terminal, and everything works fine, the python program starts as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.